# Rcpp map return

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to return a map from c++ to r.
My code in c++ is the following (as found in https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/tinytest/cpp/wrap.cpp):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector map_string_int(){
    std::map< std::string, int > m ;
     m["b"] = 100;
    m["a"] = 200;
    m["c"] = 300;
    return wrap(m);
}
```

My r code is the following:

```
require(Rcpp)
Rcpp::sourceCpp(test.cpp')
map_string_int()
```

Although the code compiles without any error, when i call the function, my r session terminates immediately.
Any ideas?

[EDIT]

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.11.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: This code runs for me without issue. Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Added the sessionInfo()!

Comment: That's strange - it works for me on two different platforms - `R version 3.0.2 / Rcpp 0.11.2 / 64-bit ubuntu-linux` and `R version 3.1.1 / Rcpp 0.11.3 / 64-bit redhat-linux`. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I would say if you don't get an answer here you should move your question to the [Rcpp mailing list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel).

Comment: I have just tested in 64-bit debian and it also worked... Could it be because of windows or cygwin-64 that i am using to provide the make and gcc compiler?

Comment: It's possible - I honestly don't know very much about compilers but I have run into a LOT of issues compiling code on Windows (especially with Rtools), so I try to stick to Linux whenever possible.

Comment: Wise words, @nrussell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to try another compiler and it worked!

I have installed Rtools compiler (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) after which just changed the system path to point to the bin folders within the Rtools installation folder.